# Achievements not readable for my Game App

Tags: facebook, achievements

I have created a Facebook application which has its category set to "Games". I've followed the documentation for defining an achievement (unique url/open graph meta tags etc) and have successfully added the achievement to my game via the graph API. However I am unable to view/read the achievements connected to my game application via the Graph API Explorer or via my own code.

In the Graph API explorer on the right where the available connections are listed, Achievements doesn't even show up as an option for the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and apologies in advance if I have missed the blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but it was from Facebook itself. Today I tried the read api and that is working for me. I hope this will be fine for you as well.

Regards